# Search with multiple tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8

I have 3 tables that are connected/have relation.

1. Posts table have many tag and one Category
2. Category table have many Posts
3. Tag table have many Posts

i want a search feature, i know how to search only use Posts (based on title).

I tried to search each tables with Where in my controller but still no luck.

```
public function Search(Request $request)
    {
        $search = $request->search;
        $posts = post::where('title', 'like', "%{$search}%")->paginate(5);

        return view('search', compact('posts'))->with('result', $search);
    }
```

For example

i have a post Titled 'Test' and with Category 'Tost' and with Tags 'Tast and Tust'

so if i type either the title, category or tags i want it to show up. how can i achieve it?

Comment: is this   Post::where() not post::where()

Comment: Have you looked into the orWhere() function? You can join your tables together and do something along the lines of orWhere('category.name', 'LIKE', '%data%');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try use whereHas method (for further info check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#querying-relations)

So would become something like:

```php
Post::query()
  ->where('title', 'like', "%$search%")
  ->orWhereHas('categories', function ($query) use ($search) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', "%$search%");
  })
```

Comment: Thank you, this is working, its weird that i already tried it last night but not working, but now its working, haha, thank you so much sir.

Answer (score 0):

You must use like this.

```
Post::where('title', 'like', '%' . Input::get('search') . '%')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you for that, however thats not my question, i can already search from post table. I need to search not only just the title of the post but also the category or tags. so if i either type or input the category/tag/title on the search it output all post related to it. Sorry if my english bad, hope you can understand it :D

Comment: There is no difference between his and yours other than you're separating your wild cards and variable with periods and not paginating the collection.